# Correct array Output php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-blade

I build this function where an array is created

```
public function getSpielplan(){
       // $spielplanVar = Spielplan::where('Spieltag', '=', 1)->get();

        $spielplanVar = Spielplan::where('Spieltag', '=', 1)->get();
            foreach($spielplanVar as $ausgabeT){
                $vereinT = Verein::where('V_ID', '=', $ausgabeT->Heimmannschaft)->get();
                   foreach($vereinT as $ausgabeVereinT){
                        $vereinTGast = Verein::where('V_ID', '=', $ausgabeT->Gastmannschaft)->get();
                            foreach($vereinTGast as $ausgabeVereinTGast){

                            $newdata =  array (
                                  'Spiel_ID' => $ausgabeT->Spielplan_ID,
                                  'Heimmannschaft' => $ausgabeVereinT->Name,
                                  'Gastmannschaft' => $ausgabeVereinTGast->Name
                                );
                }
            }
        }
        return view('spielplan')->with('alleSpiele', $newdata);
    }
```

My View is this...

```
div class="col-xs-6">
                label for="">Spielauswahl</label>
                select class="form-control input-sm" name="spiele" id="spiele">

                foreach($alleSpiele as $alleSpieleOutput)     
                    option value="{!! $alleSpieleOutput !!}">{{$alleSpieleOutput}}/option>     
                endforeach
                /select>
            /div>
```

Now I have 2 questions.
1. In the form controller option, I get only 1 row from the array Spiel_ID, Heimmannschaft and Gastmannschaft. Why? 2. How can I use in the  specific fields? alleSpieleOutput -> Spiel_ID for example is not working

Answer (score 0):

Add in this line...

```
 $newdata = array();    // Create an array for the data
 foreach($spielplanVar as $ausgabeT){
```

Change the line...

```
 $newdata =  array (
      'Spiel_ID' => $ausgabeT->Spielplan_ID,
      'Heimmannschaft' => $ausgabeVereinT->Name,
      'Gastmannschaft' => $ausgabeVereinTGast->Name
 );
```

to

```
 $newdata[] =  array (
      'Spiel_ID' => $ausgabeT->Spielplan_ID,
      'Heimmannschaft' => $ausgabeVereinT->Name,
      'Gastmannschaft' => $ausgabeVereinTGast->Name
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You using array as String?  And name variable on view and in the controller should be a same. And you can not use array as object, for this convert array to json, for example